# default case class argument depending on other arguments scala

Tags: scala, case-class

In `scala` I'm not allowed to perform the following:

```
case class Terminal(value: Double, name: String = value.toString)
```

Moreover I also cannot do this:

```
case class Terminal(value: Double)(name: String = value.toString)
```

I understand the multiple parameter list approach is not supported for constructors.

Is is there a way to define in the `apply` method in order to make this possible?

Expected behavior:

```
Terminal(1.0) // => Terminal (1.0, "1.0")
```

Comment: You have to call it like `Terminal(dbl)()` the second way, he wants just `Terminal(dbl)`. (On 2.12.1 here)

Comment: May I suggest removing "multiple param. list is not supported for constructors"? It *does* work; it just isn't what you want because it requires calling like `Terminal(dbl)()`. Just so someone in the future looking at this isn't confused.

Comment: Specifically for case classes, `case class Terminal(value: Double)(name: String = value.toString)` has a problem in that `name` doesn't participate in `equals`/`toString`/`unapply`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this in the case class itself, and it won't make a constructor, but it is possible through the `apply` method on the companion.

```
case class Terminal(value: Double, name: String)
object Terminal {
  def apply(value: Double): Terminal = Terminal(value, value.toString)
}
```

Note that:

```
def apply(value: Double, name: String = value.toString) = new Terminal(value, name)
```

is an error because it conflicts with the autogenerated `apply`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just want this?

```
case class Terminal(value: Double) {
    val name = a.toString
}
```